Stopping all threads after PTRACE_ATTACH
I am developing an application that will modify file descriptors in another process. It isn't anything serious, I just wanted to expand my knowledge a bit and chose this topic. To do it, I want to inject machine code to executable page of a running process and I need to control the process with ptrace() calls. I noticed that when I attach my test debugger to another process with ptrace() request PTRACE_ATTACH, the debugger gets a signal like this:
SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_TRAPPED, si_pid=71336, si_uid=1000, si_status=SIGSTOP, si_utime=0, si_stime=0}
After ptrace() request PTRACE_ATTACH I call wait() and the process is stopped but only if it is single threaded. If it has multiple threads, the other threads continue to run. I thought that it will be enough to call kill() with signal SIGSTOP and this works but immediately after a call to kill(), the debugger doesn't receive SIGCHLD signal. It appears that the process is stopped twice, first time after a call to kill() and then after I am done with process memory modifications after calling ptrace() with request PTRACE_DETACH, when debugger receives another signal like:
SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_STOPPED, si_pid=71336, si_uid=1000, si_status=SIGSTOP, si_utime=0, si_stime=0}
In total, debugger flow looks like this:

    ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, 71336)            = 0
    --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_TRAPPED, si_pid=71336, si_uid=1000, si_status=SIGSTOP, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
    wait4(-1, [{WIFSTOPPED(s) && WSTOPSIG(s) == SIGSTOP}], 0, NULL) = 71336
    kill(71336, SIGSTOP)                    = 0
     
    ///// All threads stopped here, do some work on process memory /////
     
    ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, 71336, NULL, 0)   = 0
    --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_STOPPED, si_pid=71336, 
    si_uid=1000, si_status=SIGSTOP, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
     
    ///// signal delivered after ptrace detach, and process is stopped again /////

The question that I would have is how to properly stop all threads in debugged process with/after PTRACE_ATTACH? I need this when modifying memory so that no thread will execute code from the page being modified.
